# How do you flush a specific URL from the Enterprise Full Page Cache?

Tags: full-page-cache

I had a look through `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor::extractContent()` to see how it determines the cache key for each page that it caches, but it's pretty complicated and there doesn't seem to be a simple way to determine the cache key for a given URL in order to remove it from the cache...?

Comment: Okay I realized now why I couldn't find this anywhere - it's not the right way to go about it.  What you're supposed to do is clear by tag not by URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess (you didn't state the reason or use case for clearing a specific URL) would be to try to approach it by clearing the cache by tags. You could register an event at some point before the script terminates and call `Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_pagecache/processor')->addRequestTag()`.

As you stated, the cache ID logic includes request and application environment information. You could poke around the `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor::_createRequestIds` and `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor::_getFullPageUrl` methods for more details on how they work.

Comment: `prepareCacheId` has the short version and in it's simplest form it's a prefix + an md5 hash of the REQUEST_URI.

Comment: @Melvyn actually this is the problem - it's not simple at all :(  I initially went this route and it worked in local environment but in production there were other things being appended to the cache key (cookies, store codes, all sorts of stuff).

Comment: @kalenjordan it depends on the use case (and I'm interested in the use case to flush by URL), you could have intercepted in the method that mangles the REQUEST_URI into an ID, so that you still have access to the pure URL. On my mobile so don't have code available. Normally, flushing a URL is not a good approach as URLs get stale based on other factors and more often then not affects more than one URL.

Comment: CMS Page URL :)  Also realized I misread your initial comment - you said "in it's simplest form" I read that as "is simple".  :)  Sorry!